# Twitter in iOS 5 leaking memory with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

[image]

Here is my code:

```
case kTweetIndex:
{
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet =
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.item.link]];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    if (![TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't Send tweet");
    }
}
```

This is just a massive amount of leak caused by twitter, and i don't know how to handle it. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing the canSendTweet first, before you create and present the modalView?

Comment: I second David. And also are you implementing the twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res)  thing ?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using it. @David yeah i do it like this, but i want to try it without it and here's the result.

Comment: You are not alone, read some of the comments [here](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/10/21/ios-5-twitter-framework-example/) and [here](http://tonyngo.net/2011/10/twitter-integration-tutorial/) I would recommend filing a [bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/).

Comment: Is 3rd party library like ShareKit a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Property of TWTweetComposeViewController or twitter class or you can one thing more alloc it in AppDelegate Class. It will work.